# Covariance term in Gradient of Gaussian Process marginal likelihood

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood, gaussian-process, hyperparameter

log  marginal likelihood for Gaussian Process as given by  [Rasmussen's: Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW5.pdf) equation 5.8 is
$$\log p(y|X, \theta) = -\frac{1}{2}y^{T} K_y^{-1}y - \frac{1}{2}\log|K_y|-\frac{n}{2}\log2\pi$$
where $K_y = K_f + \sigma^2I$ is the covariance matrix for the noisy targets $y$ (and $K_f$ is the covariance matrix for the noise-free latent $f$) and $\theta$ is hyperparameters (parameters of kernel function).

Partial derivatives of the marginal likelihood w.r.t. the hyperparameters is given in eqn. 5.9.

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_i} \mathrm{log}P(y|x, \theta) = \frac{1}{2}y^TK^{-1}\frac{\partial K}{\partial\theta_i}K^{-1}y^T 
-\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}\big(K^{-1}\frac{\partial K}{\partial\theta_i}\big) $$
Now my doubt is what is $K$ in equation 5.9, does it represents $K_y$ or $K_f$
or something else.

Comment: It represents $K_y$. You are just differentiating the first Eq.

Comment: Can I also differentiate and optimize for $\sigma$

Comment: Yes, you can optimize wrt $\sigma$, but in some cases the solution is not good, as you need also to control numerical quality of the problem via $\sigma$.

Comment: then I would optimize $\sigma$ using MCMC, any other suggestion for estimating $\sigma$

Comment: Look up the GPML code. http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/code/matlab/doc/
It's possibly also discussed in the book. You might want to do different computations depending on wheter $\sigma$ is large or small, in order to maintain numerical precision.

Comment: @AlexeyZaytsev Not sure if this is worth another question, so I'll start as a comment. I think in the book he optimizes wrt $\sigma$, but I'm running into the problem of the stability of K if I don't control $\sigma$ pretty tightly. Can you point me towards a reference for estimating it. For now I'm just doing a line search to find the lowest value of $\sigma$ that will keep the condition number of K under some value, but that doesn't seem like a good approach.

Comment: hello @DavidKozak, in the book he only optimizing with respect to $\theta$ (parameters of covariance function) and not wrt $\sigma$. Matlab's documentation on Gaussian Process have been useful to me. have a look at tutorials: https://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/gaussian-process-regression.html , https://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/exact-gpr-method.html

Comment: @DavidKozak Conditioning on the condition number of $K$ works well for me in many practical problems. Also you can add some prior on $\sigma$, e.g. you can use normal prior for log of it.

Comment: Right on, thanks pkj and @alexey. Those Matlab tutorials seem very comprehensive, I'll spend some time with them. Yes, Alexey I thought about hyperpriors, I just haven't got around to working through the math to know how that will play out. Thanks for the insight into the practical use, it's been disorienting going from math land to practical land and back so it's good to know it's the right track